# play 2.3.6, java 1.8 how to pass session to scala templates

Tags: java, scala, session, playframework

I know there are a lot of SO links with this in discussion but either they are related to old framework version or they don't work for me,

what I want to do is pass session to scala templates without having to pass them explicitly form controllers, I didn't find examples(working) of implicit parameters in play 2.3.x version, my view is rendered as `ok(welcome.render(msg))` and in my template I'm doing `@(notice: String)(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session)` but it gives me `method render in class welcome cannot be applied to given types;` error, I also tried with

`@(notice: String)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[Any])`
`@(notice: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)`

but none seem to work, I know I can pass required session values from the controller but I'm trying to send some user data that'd be required in the navbar which would be required in each view so I don't want to send it from the controllers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to give full path of your template file `ok(views.html.welcome.render(msg))`, and compile your project, this might solve your issue.

Comment: I don't see how that'd make any difference

Comment: For new template before compilation, when you try to render it from controller, if you didn't specify full path of template it shows error `template cannot be applied to given types`, when you give full path it works.

Comment: I don't think it applies to my case though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play Session might be retrieved from scala templates by session helper, just as the statement below. Altough I'm using play 2.2.1, it may work for you as well.
Btw, i have never needed implicit parameter in order to reach it.

```
@session.get("keyvalue")
```

I may have misunderstood your question, but if you want to get session values from view that's the standard way.

Comment: thansk a lot, I just got on the wrong ways because of mention of the keyword 'implicit'